# In ChartJS 3.9.1 is there any solution, to show only gridlines and labels at a specific point?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using ChartJs 3.9.1 to visualize my data. I need to show the day when the atcual value was created, so I chose the solution in which I mark the days with colorcodes in fill bckColor. So far so good.

But i found it still confusing, as the X axis labels doesn't fit with the color changes. So my question is, is there any way to show the vertical grid lines, and its label only at the point, where the colorcode (the day index of the value) changes?

Thanks for nay help!

Here's a sample code:

```
function setCharts() {

    const colorDays = ['#54bebe', '#76c8c8', '#98d1d1', '#badbdb', '#dedad2', '#e4bcad', '#df979e', '#d7658b', '#c80064'];

    let dataRandom = fillRandomValues();

    const tab = document.getElementById('tabCharts');
    tab.innerHTML = '';

    let ctx = document.createElement('canvas');
    ctx.id = 'canvasChart';

    new Chart(ctx, {
        
        type: 'line',
        data: {

            idxDays: dataRandom.listIdxDays,
            labels: dataRandom.listIdxValues,
            datasets: [{
                
                label: `example`,
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: '#54bebe',
                borderColor: '#54bebe',
                borderWidth : 2,
                pointRadius: 0,
                data: dataRandom.listValues,
                segment: {

                    backgroundColor: (ctx) => (colorDays[ctx.chart.data.idxDays[ctx.p0DataIndex]]),
                }
            }]
        },
        options: {

            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {

                y: {

                    beginAtZero: true          
                }
            } 
        }
    });

    tab.appendChild(ctx);
}

function fillRandomValues() {

    let data = {

        listValues: [], // actual values
        listIdxValues: [],  // idx of the value in the array (1, 2, 3...) for the chart data.labels
        listIdxDays: [], // the idx of the day the value created (0:mon, 1:tue...) for the color coding
        listIsDayChanged: [], // if the day of the values changes (true, false)
    };

    let dayActual = 0;

    for (let d = 0; d < 100; d++) { // 100 random value

        let rand = 50 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));

        if (rand < 55) {

            dayActual == 6 ? dayActual = 0 : dayActual++;
            data.listIsDayChanged[d] = true;
        } else {

            data.listIsDayChanged[d] = false;
        }

        data.listValues[d] = rand;
        data.listIdxDays[d] = dayActual;
        data.listIdxValues[d] = d;
    }

    return data;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1"></script>

<div id="tabCharts" class="tabContent" style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Which grid lines are drawn can be selected through the `lineWidth` property,
which is [scriptable](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/general/options.html#scriptable-options)
(a feature you have already used for `segment.backgroundColor` option).

However, grid lines are confined to ticks only, so if ticks are selected according to
the desired criterion, there's no need to further select grid lines through `lineWidth`.

Ticks can be selected/filtered in one of the axis [callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/axes/#callbacks),
for instance in `afterBuildTicks`.

A difficult problem in the case of ticks manipulation is that of avoiding tick labels
overlapping. In the case of the code below I choose to hide the labels
of consecutive values - that is, if `15` and `16` are labels that passed the filter,
don't display `16`. This works well for the specific type of labels and the
chart size in the OP code, but should be modified/adapted to other cases.

```js
function setCharts() {
    const colorDays = ['#54bebe', '#76c8c8', '#98d1d1', '#badbdb', '#dedad2', '#e4bcad', '#df979e', '#d7658b', '#c80064'];

    let dataRandom = fillRandomValues();

    const tab = document.getElementById('tabCharts');
    tab.innerHTML = '';

    let ctx = document.createElement('canvas');
    ctx.id = 'canvasChart';

    new Chart(ctx, {

        type: 'line',
        data: {

            idxDays: dataRandom.listIdxDays,
            labels: dataRandom.listIdxValues,
            datasets: [{
                label: `example`,
                fill: true,
                backgroundColor: '#54bebe',
                borderColor: '#54bebe',
                borderWidth : 2,
                pointRadius: 0,
                data: dataRandom.listValues,
                segment: {
                    backgroundColor: (ctx) => (colorDays[ctx.chart.data.idxDays[ctx.p0DataIndex]]+'aa')
                }
            }]
        },
        options: {

            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            scales: {
                x: {
                    grid: {
                        //color: '#ccc',
                        tickColor: '#bbb',
                        lineWidth: 1
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        autoSkip: false,
                        callback: (value, index, ticks) => ticks[index]._hide ? '' :  value
                    },
                    afterBuildTicks(ctx){
                        ctx.ticks = ctx.ticks.filter((_, index) =>
                         index === 0 || index === ctx.chart.data.idxDays.length - 1 ||
                            ctx.chart.data.idxDays[index] !== ctx.chart.data.idxDays[index - 1])
                            .map((tick, index, ticks) => {
                                if(index > 0 && !ticks[index-1]._hide && tick.value - ticks[index-1].value <= 1){
                                    tick._hide = true
                                }
                                return tick;
                            });
                    }
                },
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    });

    tab.appendChild(ctx);
    tab.style.display = "block";
}

function fillRandomValues() {

    let data = {

        listValues: [], // actual values
        listIdxValues: [],  // idx of the value in the array (1, 2, 3...) for the chart data.labels
        listIdxDays: [], // the idx of the day the value created (0:mon, 1:tue...) for the color coding
        listIsDayChanged: [], // if the day of the values changes (true, false)
    };

    let dayActual = 0;

    for (let d = 0; d < 100; d++) { // 100 random value

        let rand = 50 + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));

        if (rand < 55) {

            dayActual == 6 ? dayActual = 0 : dayActual++;
            data.listIsDayChanged[d] = true;
        } else {

            data.listIsDayChanged[d] = false;
        }

        data.listValues[d] = rand;
        data.listIdxDays[d] = dayActual;
        data.listIdxValues[d] = d;
    }

    return data;
}

setCharts();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1"></script>

<div id="tabCharts" class="tabContent" style="display: none; width: 1000px; height: 500px;"></div>
```